# Updating a value of a 2-dimensional array PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a column that stores data in a 2-dimensional array as follows: `{{23, 3}, {56, 5}}`. I would like to update the value in the second dimension of the array, such as update 3 to 8 and update 5 to 9 so the array becomes `{{23, 8}, {56, 9}}`.

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I can't understand the criteria behind that either (would you like to update those values adding a random value to them?)

Comment: yes...i am trying to learn the value of second dimension(it is 3 for first element and 5 for second element) of an element in an array and then manipulate (by adding some number) it based on that value.

Comment: What is your current query which isn't working as expected?

Comment: actually i am new to postgresql and trying to learn it, so i am just curious about how to do this. Besides i have no idea what this query would look like or should be, because i havent seen any documentation about this so far.

Comment: Here is a [Doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING) page you could find interesting. The best way to learn something is trial and error, so try to build a query and we will eventually fix it.

Comment: this worked; UPDATE foo_table SET arraycolumn[indexofarray][1][1] =value1, arraycolumn[indexofarray][2][1]=value2 WHERE column=value ;